# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 isEmpty() or is.Blank() with char

Tags: java, string, char

This program asks for a string with a lower case vowel. If it has a lower case vowel the parrot will repeat the string, but if not it will ask again.

I get this error when the String is empty or blank. I know that the position 0 in the char is empty but I don't know how to fix it. Should I use a for loop with the length of the string?

```java
while (true) {
    System.out.println(
            "El lloro pregunta paraula que comenci amb vocal en minúscules");
    String paraula = Entrada.readLine();

    if (paraula.charAt(0) == 'a' 
            || paraula.charAt(0) == 'e' 
            || paraula.charAt(0) == 'i' 
            || paraula.charAt(0) == 'o'
            || paraula.charAt(0) == 'u') {
        System.out.println("El lloro diu: " + paraula);
    }

    if (paraula.isEmpty() || paraula.isBlank()) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("Adéu");
```

Comment: Test if the string is null, empty or blank before you test the charAt(0)

Comment: It makes little sense to test `if(paraula.isEmpty() || paraula.isBlank())` **after** you already called functions on that String that require it not to be empty.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `if (paraula.startsWith("a")` etc, which handles the empty case.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("El lloro pregunta paraula que comenci amb vocal en minúscules");
    String paraula = Entrada.readLine();
    if(paraula.length()!=0 && "aeiou".indexOf(paraula.charAt(0))>=0)
        System.out.println("El lloro diu: " + paraula);
    if(paraula.isBlank()) // No need to check for empty String as you have checked it before
        break;
}
System.out.println("Adéu");
```

Comment: the indexOf helped me a lot

Comment: btw if i wanted to check the last vowel of the string should i use the .endsWith()?

Comment: Will the last vowel be the last character of the String?

Comment: yes, like in this case i am checking the first char

Comment: @khandaniyal You can use `startsWith("vowel")` for String starting with a vowel and you can use `endsWith("vowel")` for String ending with a vowel. Do not forget to put your vowel(character) in `"vowel"`